# writing data to firebase is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

**I am trying to insert some data to firebase but its saying customerName is not defined. I don't understand whats the problem the code. Below is my code. Thank you.**

```
var orderDetailsRef = database.ref('orderDetails'); 
    var customerName = $scope.CustomerName;
    var customerContactNumber = $scope.customerContactNumber;
    var pickdroneId = $scope.pickdroneId;
    var orderId = $scope.orderId;
    var orderDate = $scope.orderDate
    var result = orderDetailsRef.push({
        customerName: CustomerName,
        customerContactNumber: customerContactNumber,
        pickdroneId: pickdroneId,
        orderId: orderId,
        orderStatus: "Initiated",
        orderDate: orderDate
    });
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Seems like a typo `CustomerName` should be `customerName`.

Comment: @PieterLaebens yeah I you are right. Thank you